# IBM Watson speech to text method returns okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset instead of response

Tags: java, ibm-watson

I am using IBM Watson speech to text in one of my current applications. Everything works well until I fire Watson's recognize method by passing the audio parameters along with other parameters.
It starts to transcribe the audio but throws this error `Exceptionnnnjava.lang.RuntimeException: okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: INTERNAL_ERROR`

The code where the Watson method is called is simply:

```
    SpeechRecognitionResults transcript = service.recognize(options).execute();;
```

I have been googling and searching similar issue for more than 2 days but could not find a solution. Is it something related to the Watson method or is the request taking too long and so I get this error in Java? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I would guess your audio upload code is broken.

Comment: I am simply passing audio file as bytes in the options, what might be broken at that end?